# How to update Linux "locate" cache

Tags: debian, locate

How can I update the cache / index of locate? I installed new packages and the files are clearly not yet indexed.
So which command do I have to commit, in order for the indexer to trigger?

I'm currently working on debian jessie (testing):
with Linux mbpc 3.13-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.13.7-1 (2014-03-25) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: If your `locate` is from the *GNU Find Utilities* project (which, if you are using Debian Jessie, it probably is), then you can find the project's website and documentation here: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/

Answer (score 187, accepted):

The command is:

```
sudo updatedb
```

See [`man updatedb`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=updatedb&manpath=Debian%20testing%20jessie) for more details.

Comment: And put it as a cron.

Comment: One remark here, this command runs for ~13 minutes on Debian Stretch RC3 and Sata SSD drive, so be patient.

Comment: @Marecky The time it takes is highly dependent on the number of files there are on your filesystem. on a new install, it can run in a matter of seconds

Comment: but the other answer says this is a bad idea...

Answer (score 34):

On OSX this is: `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`

Which can be linked with: `sudo ln -s /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb /usr/local/bin/updatedb`

Seems silly to have to make a symbolic link for a standard unix command, but there it is.

Comment: I confirm that on January 2024 (with OSX 13.6.1) the path is still correct.

Answer (score 13):

While the answer:

```bash
sudo updatedb
```

is technically correct, it is almost never a good idea to run `updatedb` on a command line by itself, if there is also a cron job installed. Depending on the Unix flavor the cronjob contains locking provisions and any amount of configuration which is not covered by the standalone `updatedb` command.

If the locate database needs to be updated frequently, it is definitely worth the effort to determine the proper cron job for a specific host and run it manually.

Depending on the administrator, the cronjob for `updatedb` may be hidden in  various locations. So a simple brute-force attempt to find the cron job would be:

```bash
( sudo crontab -l > /tmp/crontab.root;
  ( echo /tmp/crontab.root; ls -1d /etc/*cron* /etc/*cron*/* ) \
  | tr '\n' '\0' \
  | xargs -0 -r -e grep -nH -e updatedb;
  rm -f /tmp/crontab.root
) 2>/dev/null
```

which shows the following result on one of my Ubuntu systems:

```
/etc/cron.daily/mlocate:5:[ -x /usr/bin/updatedb.mlocate ] || exit 0
/etc/cron.daily/mlocate:21:flock --nonblock /run/mlocate.daily.lock $IONICE /usr/bin/updatedb.mlocate
```

The correct command to update the locate database in this case is therefore

```bash
sudo /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
```

A more systematic approach is to determine the package which provides `locate` and `updatedb`.

E.g., on an OS with apt/dpkg packaging you can find which flavor of locate is installed with:

```bash
dpkg -S locate | grep /bin/
```

In my case it is:

```
mlocate: /usr/bin/updatedb.mlocate
```

To see, which cron job if any is responsible, run:

```
dpkg -L mlocate | grep cron
```

Which in my case shows:

```
/etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.daily/mlocate
```

To update the database, run the cron job as root:

```bash
sudo /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
```

If there is no cronjob, and updatedb by itself does not work, try finding your installed flavor with:

```bash
dpkg -L mlocate | grep /bin/
```

which returns:

```
/usr/bin/mlocate
/usr/bin/updatedb.mlocate
```

**Update**

There is yet another approach to run updatedb on a daily basis using a oneshot systemd service named *updatedb.service*, *mlocate-updatedb.service*, etc. This service is triggered by a corresponding timer *updatedb.timer*, *mlocate-updatedb.timer*. Here is a sample service file, I found in a repository:

```ini
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/updatedb
IOSchedulingClass=idle
```

Although it just calls `ionice -c 3 /usr/bin/updatedb` in this case, it still is better to start the service, making sure it is run in the correct environment without the need to double and triple check the service file for changes introduced by the system maintainers during updates:

```bash
sudo systemctl start updatedb.service
```

Besides examining the package file list, checking for a service can be done with a command like:

```bash
systemctl list-unit-files | grep 'updatedb\|locate'
```

Comment: `sudo crontab -l` yelds `no crontab for root` on linux mint. What could be the issue ?

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa Usually there is no crontab for root. So it is not an issue. There are either scripts in /etc/cron.monthly, /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.weekly, which are exectued as root. Or there are crontab entries in /etc/crontab, /etc/cron.d, where the user can be specified. However, some administrators do add a user crontab for root, so the `crontab -l`  this is just used to make sure.

Comment: For me (on manjaro) there was no crontab entry for updatedb but had systemd entries instead `/usr/lib/systemd/system/updatedb.service, /usr/lib/systemd/system/updatedb.timer`  so I used `sudo systemctl start updatedb`. And I assume it is no different from running sudo updatedb

Comment: @PhaniRithvij Thanks for the info. I have updated my answer accordingly. Your assumption that there is no difference from running `sudo updatedb` is wrong. Trivially, you have no idea, which `updatedb` is started, if you do not specify an explicit path name. Other things are scheduling class and provisions to avoid parallel invocations of updatedb. And there is always a chance that an OS update introduces modifications beyond the wildest imagination ;-) So, if you know, what you are doing, go ahead. I usually assume, that I in fact do not know what I am doing.

Comment: On Fedora 36 I did `systemctl enable plocate-updatedb.timer`.

Comment: @theHutt This only enables the timer, it does not trigger the execution of the service, which is what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

The "locate" package usually comes with a cronjob which runs on a daily basis and updates the locate database.

You can run the cronjob manually to enforce an update of the locate database.

On Debian, you can do this:

```
sudo /etc/cron.daily/locate
```

Note that this can run a while, depending on the system performance and the amount of files to scan.